# Composing view models with Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

The below code lightly illustrates what I am trying to do with 2 models. Lets say we have a `Book` model and an `Author` model. First we fetch a list of `Books` using a service that returns a type `Observable<Book>`. We then use `*ngFor` to iterate through each one, but we want to also display the `Author` next to the book so in our iteration we have some HTML like this:

```
<span>{{ getAuthorName(book) | async }}</span>
```

`getAuthorName` has its own request go out on the `AuthorService` to fetch the author by `ID`.  The problem is that when we return an `Observable<string>` here, the browser completely crashes because change detection runs amok due to the fact that a "new" observable is returned on each digest cycle which causes change detection to run again, endlessly, right?

The below code can easily be put into a StackBlitz and reproduced (I didn't link to it because it blows up your browser CPU)

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of getData() | async">
    {{ getOtherData(item.id) | async }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  getData() {
    return of([{
      id: 1
    },{
      id: 2
    },{
      id: 3
    }]);
  }

  getOtherData(id: number) {
    const data = of([{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Matt'
    },{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Steve'
    },{
      id: 3,
      name: 'Alice'
    }]);

    return data.pipe(
      map(x => x.find(d => d.id == id))
    )
  }
}
```

Obviously there are some optimizations like caching of the Authors, etc, that could be done here, but in general, how is this scenario supposed to be handled in the world of RXJS? I know there are entire frameworks for dealing with state like Akita and ngrx, but what if I don't want to deal with all that and just want to build my app with raw `rxjs`?  What is the intended solution to this problem? Do you use some other rxjs operators to stop this from happening? (I couldn't find anythat helped this since it was returning a new `Obserable` each time anyways) Do you have to only use view models and not methods? That way ther eis always just a single reference to the observable? (e.g. `BookAuthorViewModel` which has a `$author` property that gets set before we iterate in the view to a single observable?

I haven't found a single solution that "feels right" and I feel like I am forced to use these state management frameworks just to do simple things like this.

Comment: I'd avoid using the template to "compose" your observables to begin with. Stick with exposing (and iterating over) a _single_ observable that does all the required composition inside a `pipe()`. The latter approach means that you can also test your observable composition by asserting on each emitted item. It also means your template markup is cleaner—it only needs to iterate over the composition results.

Comment: Take a look at the pattern I use for simple services with a library I wrote called RxCache https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb It is not a state management library but a helper library to reduce the amount of rxjs code you need to  write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reasons you shouldn't use functions in the html template. I recommend to merge the data before using it in the template. This can look like this:

```
this.books$ = this.myService.getBooks();
this.authors$ = this.myService.getAuthors();

this.bookAuthorPairs$ = combineLatest([this.books$, this.authors$]).pipe(
  map(([books, authors]) => books.map(
    (book) => {
      return { book, author: authors.find(author => book.authorId === author.id) };
    }
  )),
);
```

Comment: Ok thanks this definitely makes sense. I will try to put all of this logic into a service as well so it can be reused.

Answer (score 3):

You should not call methods in your view. If you have a method that returns an observable then you get a new observable being created each time change detention checks the value.

```
data$ = of([{
  id: 1
},{
  id: 2
},{
  id: 3
}]);

otherData$ = of([{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Matt'
},{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Steve'
},{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Alice'
}]);
```

and then bind to the observable

```
<li *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">
  {{ otherData$ | async | find: item.id }}
</li>
```

and make the find pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'find'
})
export class FindPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(options, id): string {
    return options.find(option => option.id === id);
  }
}
```

StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vgosc

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to combine the streams in the service.

For each book, you want the author's name. In my example, for each ToDo, it gets the user's name.

```
  todos$ = this.http
    .get<ToDo[]>(this.todoUrl)
    .pipe(catchError(err => throwError("Error occurred")));

  todosWithUser$ = this.todos$.pipe(
    mergeMap(todos =>
      forkJoin(
        todos.map(todo =>
          this.http.get<User>(`${this.userUrl}/${todo.userId}`).pipe(
            map(user =>({
                  ...todo,
                  usersName: user.name
                } as ToDo)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-users-todos-deborahk

The `todos$` stream gets all of the todos (or books in your case).

It uses `mergeMap` to map and merge each ToDo in the list. This is needed to automatically subscribe to the "inner" Observable that retrieves the user.

The `forkJoin` allows us to process the array of ToDo's and find the user for each one. Then joins them all back into an array.

The last `map` adds the `usersName` property onto each Todo.